# version-independent dynamic linking with boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, shared-libraries

#### question

How can I compile a shared library linking with version-independent boost shared library?
My cmakelists.txt is like as follows

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS serialization)
...
target_link_libraries(_omplpy PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${otherdeps})
```

And, after compiling this, I checked dependency by `ldd` command and it shows that only the dependency of boost libraries are too specific (seems that version 1.71.0 is specified, though other libraries does not care about the minor version)

```
h-ishida@stone-jsk:~/python/ompl-python-thin$ ldd build/_omplpy.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd34ca9000)
    libboost_serialization.so.1.71.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so.1.71.0 (0x00007f208012f000)
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0 (0x00007f2080111000)
distir  libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f20800ee000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f207ff0c000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f207fdbd000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f207fda0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f207fbae000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f20812a6000)
```

The problem is, boost libraries version are different for different ubuntu distributions, thus my compiled shard library _omplpy cannot be used in different distribution.

#### context (maybe unrelated)

I am trying to distribute a python package where a shared library linked with boost stuff is inside. Because python wheel (binary version of package) is only python-version (like 2.7, 3.8), os (mac, windows, ldistirinux), and archtecture dependent (like x86_64, aarch64), it seems impossible to distribute packages dependent on specific ubuntu distribution. For your information, the package mentioned is https://github.com/HiroIshida/ompl-thin-python and corresponding CMakeLists.txt is here  https://github.com/HiroIshida/ompl-thin-python/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I decided to build static boost library with -fPIC option and compile the target library with linking that. It's much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I compile a shared library linking with version-independent boost shared library?

You can't, because the different boost libraries are *not* ABI-compatible. If you somehow succeeded in linking your library with "version-independent boost", the result would be a runtime crash.

Read about the reasons for external library versioning [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter5-5.html).

P.S.

> I decided to build static boost library with -fPIC option and compile the target library with linking that.

That *is* much easier, but unless you are *very* careful with symbol hiding, this approach will cause runtime crashes (if you are lucky) as soon as someone tries to use your python package in program which uses a *different* version of boost libraries (due to symbol collision and ABI incompatibility). And if you are unlucky, symbol collision may cause other *very hard to find* bugs.

Comment: Mind you, it would result in a runtime crash **iff you're lucky**. It could also lead to thermo-nuclear war or your puppy being cut into 3 unequal pieces. Excellent point about symbol visibility too.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if you got what I try to mean, but I meant build boost like this https://github.com/HiroIshida/ompl-thin-python/blob/master/release/Dockerfile#L22-L26 and compile with `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)` cmake option. Because boost is statically linked into, I think there is no problem even though sameone uses different version from mine. Am i right?

Comment: @orematasaburo "I think there is no problem" -- sadly you are mistaken. See e.g. this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62897619/50617